Как исправить ошибку E_FAIL 0x80004005 при старте машины в VirtualBox?
При попытке запуска iso установщика almalinux сталкиваюсь с ошибкой E_FAIL 0x80004005.
Пробовал решения из https://remontka.pro/e_fail-0x80004005-virtualbox/ ничего не помогло.
Антивирусов сторонних на пк нет, виртуализация включена, образ и vb качал с официальных сайтов.
Логи виртуалбокса залил сюда - https://pastebin.com/PhYWBhZF

¿На какой системе стоит VirtualBox, сколько там памяти?

@user7860670 win10 x64, всего 16gb ram

¿Это нормальная система или урезанная "сборка"?

Нормальная, тоже с официального образа ставилась. Плюс установлены все последние обновления, так что дело тоже не в этом

¿А через Hyper-V не пробовали ставить? Свежие версии VirtualBox работают поверх Hyper-V

@user7860670 не пробовал, сейчас попробую через vmware поставить, мне кажется дело в виртуалбоксе

@user7860670 да, на vmware все хорошо. но хотелось бы с вб разобраться
